# How to display Null result with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I'm new to SQL and having some difficultly. I'm hoping someone could clear some stuff up for me.

This is my issue. I want to display all of the categories that an actor has played in and the amount of films they have played in that category. So for example they have played in action movies 5 times. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.name AS "Category_Name"
      , Count(c.name) AS "Count"
  FROM category c
  JOIN  film_category fc 
    ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
  JOIN film f 
    ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
  JOIN film_actor fa 
    ON f.film_id = fa.film_id 
  JOIN actor a 
    ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE a.first_name = "Kevin" 
   AND a.last_name = "Bloom"
 GROUP 
    BY c.name
ORDER 
    BY c.name ASC;
```

This will display all of the categories and the amount of times "Kevin Bloom" has played in each however it will not display NULL values for categories he has not played in and I need it to. I have spend a few hours trying to figure this out but it either didn't help or I wasn't able to understand it.

From what I gather the WHERE clause is causing this issue. I also believe I will likely need to use a LEFT JOIN instead and possibly a sub query. I'm a little shaky on both of these things when used in conjunction. If anyone can offer some help to a first time learner I would really appreciate it!

Comment: yes LEFT JOINs and move the where clause to the ON condition of the join with the actor table

Comment: What @Matt said. And here is some nice visual explanation of the JOIN types: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Yes. Change the inner joins to left joins, and change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.name AS "Category_Name", Count(a.actor_id) AS "Count"
FROM category c
    LEFT JOIN  film_category fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
    LEFT JOIN film f ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
    LEFT JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id 
    LEFT JOIN actor a
       ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
       AND a.first_name = 'Kevin' AND a.last_name = 'Bloom'
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name ASC;
```

Per your comment, why to use `AND` versus `WHERE` is about how `WHERE` is evaluated when executing. The `WHERE` clause limits the entire result set by the condition(s) you specify.  Whereas the `ON` conditions only limit what is allowed to match the records and not necessarily the entire results set when an `OUTER JOIN` is used.  So If you put a `WHERE` condition in that limits results based on the `RIGHT` side of your `LEFT JOIN` it becomes and `INNER JOIN` because it tells SQL that you only want the results that match and because only some `categories` match that `actor` you would only get those categories.  However by putting the condition in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` your results are not limited and all categories will be returned but only actors matching your criteria will be considered.

Comment: Hey Matt just wanted to say Thanks for the help. Why is it that you change WHERE to AND?

Comment: because AND here reflects that it is part of the ON condition for the actor table.  So it will give you only the results that match that condition in your join.  If you switched to WHERE then you would essentially get the same results as an INNER JOIN which you didn't want.  I will try to expand my answer a little with a better explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation I appreciate it!

Comment: your welcome if it helped you out and worked for you please don't hesitate to accept my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `LEFT JOIN`, but you have to be careful:

```
  SELECT c.name AS Category_Name, Count(a.actor_id) AS "Count"
  FROM category c LEFT JOIN
       film_category fc 
       ON c.category_id = fc.category_id LEFT JOIN
       film f 
       ON fc.film_id = f.film_id LEFT JOIN
       film_actor fa 
       ON f.film_id = fa.film_id LEFT JOIN
       actor a 
       ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id AND a.first_name = 'Kevin' AND a.last_name = 'Bloom'
  GROUP BY c.name
  ORDER BY c.name ASC;
```

Notes:

- `LEFT JOIN` is key to the solution.
- Notice the `COUNT()` has changed to count the id from `actor`.  This will return `0` for categories where he has not acted.
- The standard delimiter for strings in SQL is a single quote, not a double quote.
- There is no need to escape column aliases, unless necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply. When I query what you had written out I actually get the same exact results that my query does above which is odd to me. Both query's only output 12 categories with a number next to each however for whatever reason it isn't outputting the last 4 categories those being the ones he hasn't acted in. So it is still missing the null values along with those categories.

Comment: Please ignore the above I made an error. Thank you again for the explanation.